# Blob and Dump file unable to create while using CVS2GIT

Tags: python, git, cvs, cvs2git

I am trying to migrate the code base from CVS to GIT.  I am using cvs2git tool in windows 10.  I have followed the instructions given by cvs2git documentation.  But when I am trying to generate the blob and dump file in my local getting error.

Below Tools I have installed in my machine

1. Smart CVS (CVSNT 2.5.05 (Mar 26 2010))
2. Python 2.4
3. GIT (git version 2.18.0.windows.1)
4. cvs2git

Steps followed

1. Extract the repository from smartCVS tool and stored in my local  (F:/CVSMigration/OrderTrackingApplication).  After extracting I am able to see the below application

   - OrderTrackingTool
   - cvsroot
2. Now I am trying to create the git-blob.dat & git-dump.dat.  I am using the below command

`python cvs2git  --encoding=utf_8 --encoding=shift_jis --blobfile=/cvs2svn-tmp/git-blob.dat --dumpfile=/cvs2svn-tmp/git-dump.dat --username=scn789 F:/CVSMigration/OrderTrackingApplication`

I am getting the below error

> **$ python cvs2git  --encoding=utf_8 --encoding=shift_jis --blobfile=/cvs2svn-tmp/git-blob.dat --dumpfile=/cvs2svn-tmp/git-dump.dat --username=guest F:/CVSMigration/OrderTrackingApplication/OrderTrackingTool Writing
>   temporary files to
>   'c:\users\vaishali\appdata\local\temp\cvs2git-ifooen'
>
> Be sure to use
>   --tmpdir='c:\users\vaishali\appdata\local\temp\cvs2git-ifooen' if you need to resume this conversion.
>
> ----- pass 1 (CollectRevsPass) ----- Examining all CVS ',v' files... ERROR: No RCS files found under
>   'F:\CVSMigration\OrderTrackingApplication\OrderTrackingTool'! Are
>   you absolutely certain you are pointing cvs2svn at a CVS repository?
>   Pass 1 complete.
>   =========================================================================== Error summary: ERROR: No RCS files found under
>   'F:\CVSMigration\OrderTrackingApplication\OrderTrackingTool'! Are
>   you absolutely certain you are pointing cvs2svn at a CVS repository?
>   Exited due to fatal error(s).**

Kindly provide your comments where I have done a mistake

Question 1: Is it right way to extract the cvs2git migration from my local repository? if it is wrong then how can i give the remote repository in the cvs2git command

Comment: You need to have the full server-side repository. If you are not the administrator of it, you will need to ask the administrator to give you a copy.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Now I have full repository of the CVS code base.
Now successfully completed the pass1,pass2 and pass3.

But the pass4 getting failed

**----- pass 4 (FilterSymbolsPass) -----
Filtering out excluded symbols and summarizing items...
ERROR: The command 'cvs -Q -R -f -d :local:F:\\CVSMigration\\ottFullRepo co -r1.1 -p -kb OTT/.cvsignore' failed with exit status=1
and the following output:
cvs [checkout aborted]: Couldn't open default trigger library: No such file or directory**

kindly provide your comments

Comment: Awaiting your comments..... Kindly help me to proceed further....

Comment: Finally I am able to generate the blob and dump file using cygWin editor but it took more than an hour.  Now I am trying to import the blob and dump file and getting the below error.
f:/CVSMigration/cvs2git-tmp/git-blob.dat f:/CVSMigration/cvs2git-tmp/git-dump.dat | git fast-import

**$ f:/CVSMigration/cvs2git-tmp/git-{blob,dump}.dat | git fast-import
f:/CVSMigration/cvs2git-tmp/git-blob.dat: line 1: blob: command not found
f:/CVSMigration/cvs2git-tmp/git-blob.dat: line 2: mark: command not found
f:/CVSMigration/cvs2git-tmp/git-blob.dat: line 3: data: command not found**

Comment: Is the original CVS repo a pure CVS repo, or is it CVSNT? If it is normal CVS, you may consider doing the conversion under linux. You may want to do that anyway. I do not know if it's important, but certainly most of the tools you're using are more native to linux, IMO.